# asp.net and wf4 correlation exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

Im pretty new to wf4 but have created a simple console app with submit, approve and reject capabilities just fine.  Im now trying to create an asp.net app that consumes the service i have created but am getting a fault exception as shown below.  This worked fine in my console app

```
The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because 
the instance key '3a552603-c92f-2424-085c-7b6fc1a0e98e' was not associated to 
an instance
```

Basically ive created 3 simple pages.  the first page is a simple form where the user submits a request.  the 2nd page just prints a list of the requests.  Clicking on one of the requests takes you to the 3rd page that prints a more detailed view of the request with an approve and decline button.  Im using a GUID for the correlation which is passed to the 3rd page through the query string.  Clicking the approve button fires the approve method of the service passing in the query string value.  Its at this point i get the exception.  The strange thing is the guid in the error message is not the same as the value im passing in.

Any ideas below is my code is that helps

1st page

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient Client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        ServiceReference1.Request R = new ServiceReference1.Request();
        R.Title = TxtRequestTitle.Text;
        R.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAmount.Text);

        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

        Client.SubmitRequest(R, g);

        Response.Write("submitted");
    }
```

2nd page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bantai11\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RequestMonkey;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True")) {
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand()) {
            com.Connection = con;

            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            com.CommandText = "Select InstanceId, Title, state from Requests";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            sda.Fill(dt);

            rp.DataSource = dt;
            rp.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

3rd page

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this._id = Request.QueryString.Get("Id");

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bantai11\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RequestMonkey;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True")) {
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand()) {
                con.Open();

                com.Connection = con;

                com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                com.CommandText = "Select InstanceId, Title, state from Requests where instanceid = '" + this._id + "'";

                SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                dr.Read();

                lblTitle.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                lblGuid.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                lblAmount.Text = "0";
            }
        }
}

protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient Client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        Client.Approve(1, this._id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that the InstanceStore couldn't find a workflow associated with that key.  It could be that the workflow has already completed or aborted with an error.  You need to get tracking data on the WorkflowService to see what is going wrong.  See [Troubleshooting Workflow Services with diagnostic logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/12/16/troubleshooting-workflow-services-with-diagnostic-logging.aspx)